# Oscillate between running service A and B with systemd

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, xorg, systemd, kodi

A livingroom multimedia solution consists of Kodi and Chromium (.xinitrc: `exec chromium-browser` ...) ran by a Raspberry Pi.

If the two processes are ran together, Kodi overrides the screen, and there is no way to minimize it, so I'm currently trying to have only one or the other run at a time. This might be more resource concious.

Currently, while both apps are easy to exit by the user, they have to type either `sudo systemctl start kodi` or `startx`. I'd like to do away with this, and have one of the apps launched as soon as the other one has finished.

I've encountered this related Q&A: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1072165/systemd-how-to-start-service-b-after-service-a-runs-to-completion, which suggest setting the service `Type=` to `oneshot` or something else. I've looked at the options in the [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Options), but I don't know enough about process forking and the inner workings of Kodi and X to select the appropriate one.

Considering the circumstances I've detailed above, what would be the best option?

Comment: First thought, simple loop in a shell: `while true; do kodi; startx; done`. Years ago I put something similar in a script file and run the file asynchronously from `/etc/rc.local`. It was more complex (`sudo -u` to run as the right user) but the basic idea was simple.

Comment: Maybe [`ExecStopPost`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=) could be pressed to this use? No idea if it would be robust enough in practice.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really promising solution! I added `ExecStopPost = +/bin/systemctl start xxx.service` to both unit files. I've also added a Conflict with the chromium service to the kodi unit file, to prevent both from running for example after a service restart. This works pretty well aside from a few peculiarities. When I start the chromium service, kodi stops and chromium launches, however, the reverse doesn't work, it just shows the shell, while systemctl status says kodi is running. I think this issue is specific to kodi. You should expand on your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Conflicts`[1](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=) and auto-restart for both Kodi and Chromium. But if both are closed, how would systemd know which one to start? It's a race. :)

Comment: This is pretty close, but there is no convenient way to start a service from either of the apps, only to shut them down. In that case, one of them would start because of the auto-restart, but how would you guarantee, that it is the correct one?